# Trans am- and pm values into numberic values

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
Time <- c("10am", "12pm", "3pm")
df <- data.frame(Time)
```

Iam looking for a way to transform the 10am in 10 and the 2pm in 14 (numeric values).

Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
df$Time <- as.character(df$Time)
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

if(grepl("am",df$Time[i])){

    x <- strsplit(df$Time[i], "am")
    first_element <- function(x){x[1]}
    df$Time[i] <- first_element(x)
    df$Time[i] <- as.numeric(x)
}

else {

  df$Time[i] <- as.character(df$Time[i])

  x <- strsplit(df$Time[i], "pm") 
  first_element <- function(x){x[1]}
  df$Time[i] <- first_element(x)
  df$Time[i] <- as.numeric(x)

   settime <- function(time){
     df$Time[i] <- time + 12
     return(df$Time[i])
   }

   df$Time[i] <- df$Time[i]


 }
}
```

And this seems to work for the am part but doesn't work for pm. It trows the following error:

```
 Error in strsplit(df$Time[i], "pm") : non-character argument
```

Any thoughts on where it goes wrong?

Comment: You have a factor column. change it to `character` as `strsplit` takes only character class i.e. `strsplit(as.character(df$Time[i]), "pm")`

Answer (score 1):

We could separate the numeric and non-numeric characters in the 'Time' using `sub`, create a two column dataset with `read.table` ('d1'), then use `ifelse` to add 12 to 'V1' elements that corresponds to 'pm' in 'V2' and those in 'V1' are less than 12.

```
d1 <- read.table(text=sub('(\\d+)(\\D+)', "\\1 \\2", 
      Time), header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
with(d1, ifelse(V2=='pm' & V1 <12, V1+12, V1))
#[1] 10 12 15
```

---

Or we can use `strptime`

```
as.numeric(format(strptime(Time, "%I%p"), '%H'))
#[1] 10 12 15
```